# Where is the memory leak in the remove method?

Tags: java, arrays, memory-management, data-structures, memory-leaks

Where is the possible memory leak in my code? There is also supposed to be a programming error too in one the methods as well, that might cause problems if I create a subclass of this class.

The add method basically just takes an index of where to add the item. For every item that occupies anything after the index in the current array, it just copies it over a spot over, and then places the item into index. I don't see what's wrong with it.

For the remove method, it does the same thing basically, except in reverse.

```
private static final int MAX_LIST = 3;
protected Object []items;  
protected int numItems;  

public MyArray()
{
    items = new Object[MAX_LIST];
    numItems = 0;
}  

/*the programming error should be in this method*/
public void add(int index, Object item)
throws  ListIndexOutOfBoundsException
{
    if (numItems > items.length)
    {
        throw new ListException("ListException on add");
    }  
    if (index >= 0 && index <= numItems)
    {

        for (int pos = numItems-1; pos >= index; pos--)  
        {
            items[pos+1] = items[pos];
        } 

        items[index] = item;
        numItems++;
    }
    else
    {

        throw new ListIndexOutOfBoundsException(
            "ListIndexOutOfBoundsException on add");
    }  
} 
/*The memory leak should be in this method*/
public void remove(int index)
throws ListIndexOutOfBoundsException
{
    if (index >= 0 && index < numItems)
    {

        for (int pos = index+1; pos < numItems; pos++) 

        {
            items[pos-1] = items[pos];
        }  
        numItems--;
    }
    else
    {

        throw new ListIndexOutOfBoundsException(
            "ListIndexOutOfBoundsException on remove");
    }  
}
```

Comment: There is 'supposed to be' an error? Is this a homework question?

Comment: The only "leak" in `remove` is that after you copy the very last item to the one before it, you do not null out the last array element.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question looks like homework to me. While asking homework questions is perfectly fine, there are some good guidelines for asking homework questions here: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812). Summarized, they are: make an attempt to solve the problem yourself first; let us know that the question is homework; make sure your class allows using Q&A for help; don't copy and paste an answer's code without first understanding what it does and how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that unused `items` elements are set to `null` otherwise objects referenced from there cannot be garbage collected.

After the for loop shifting down the items add a line:

```
items[numItems-1] = null;
```

Comment: so once everything is shifted down, the uppermost index still has the same object it did before. I see it now thanks.